# database performance: how do more columns in a table impact design / development / performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a program that captures many different types of structured messages. I need to persist the messages to database. What is the forum's view on design and performance, between:

(a) using one big table for all message types, so to handle any new message type, new columns are added to the big table. So the database is one table that may end up having 100's of columns.

(b) using a tables for each message type, so for a new message type, a new table is added to the database

By performance I mean in terms of searching all messages (i.e. searching one table versus a search across joined tables) and in terms of development work (i.e. knowledge transfer between developers) and maintenance (i.e. when something goes wrong).

This sounds a bit like it's about normalisation, but I am not sure it is.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you are asking for an opinion.  If you have two different data layouts and a set of queries and operations that you want to do, then that question is more reasonable.

Comment: You should consider if you wish to separate the messages logically into different tables because they have a different structure; or if you wish to separate the messages physically into different partitions within the same table because of performance.

Comment: One of your tags is relational-database.  That's a better option than either of the ones you suggested.  If you are not sure why I would say such a thing, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read you right,  choice (a) amounts to what is called the "One True Lookup Table"  (OTLT).  OTLT is an antipattern.  You can research it on the web.

Performance is degraded because the lookup has to be done on two fields, the type and the code.  With separate tables for each type,  the lookup is just on the code.

Queries are more complex, and therefore more likely to be in error.

Data management is harder if you want separate entry forms for each type.  If you are going to have just one true type entry form,  you need to be careful when entering new lookup values.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes with separate tables we get better performance because we don't need a type lookup. Thanks... I have been reading http://www.dbforums.com/database-concepts-design/1619660-otlt-eav-design-why-do-people-hate.html

Comment: I also get that reading data is much more complex. For example, you cannot take a cursor of select * data, you have to refer to each column.